# How to make HTML5 upload progress bar works with input type submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hi there i am currenty working on one upload progress bar.

Here is the code that is showing the upload progress bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "mylistener.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <div id="loaded_n_total"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i change this lines to look like this:
`<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mylistener.php" method="post">`
and
`<input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">`
Notice that i've changed the input type from `button` to `submit`.

In this way it's giving me error "Upload Aborted" instead of printing the upload progress bar.

When i do that it's submiting the form BUT it's not showing the upload progress bar.
So my question is how i can use input type submit and action="mylistener.php" in my HTML form and also make the upload progress bar working.
Where is the problem in this Javascript so it's not working in the way i want?

Comment: You should avoid posting questions on the same code simultanteously and just bundle it up into one thread (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819674/javascript-and-ajax-post-method) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818284/html5-and-javascript-upload-progress-bar))

Comment: why actually submit if you're using ajax? that's redundant. ajax provide the progress indication, forms don't. you can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the: input type="button" to input type="submit"
the page actually reloads. Therefore it shows upload aborted.
if you want to change the input type to "submit" then add this line of code to your uploadFile function:

```
    function uploadFile(){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //here is your rest of the code
    }
```

now your code will work..